# How to transition from one view to another view in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui

I want to transition from right to left, full-screen custom presentation. I should be able to custom animate the parent view and the presenting view, all in SwiftUI.

I'm looking for something similar to `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` in UIKit.

Comment: Just search... [some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A12299030+transition+move)

Comment: I did, none of them seem to work as exactly as I want. I wish NavigationLink was at least customizable. What I'm looking for is: the fromView scales down when the toView slides from right to left. I don't think they support fine custom transitions at the moment.